# Targeting one endpoint 100 times efficient way

Tags: .net, json, rest, endpoint

just a small dumb question about the most efficient way to achieve this:
I have 100 requests towards same endpoint (extracting some data from file with 100 rows and then creating json data out of it and targeting post endpoint with that data). Is there smarter way to achieve this than writing for loop program (for example in .NET) which would go through each entry and do this?

Cheers

Comment: potentially something async would work, and allow concurrent requests (the idea being to speed things up), but it depends on how many concurrent requests the endpoint will accept from a single client (either due to performance limitations or active enforcement of limits by the API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to really improve this would be to ask the creator of the endpoint if it would be possible to have an API that you can pass a collection of inputs and that returns a collection of results. This way you would only need one request.

If that's not possible, then you will have to loop (maybe in parallel, maybe sequential, but it will be 100 requests).